# Error in using PHPSpreadsheet: uncaught error

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I have this code to send data for excel printing but I encounter this error:

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "vendor\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld.php on line 10**

```
<?php
// (A) LOAD & USE PHPSPREADSHEET LIBRARY
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use vendor\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use vendor\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;
use vendor\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer;


$file_name = 'excelfile.xlsx';
$spreadsheet = vendor\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($file_name);
```

how can I resolve this error? Thanks.

Comment: Please read the [document](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: don't use `vendor` in your namespace's